Why does AsObservable used with BroadCastBlock not get all values
I was experimenting with having a BroadcastBlock also broadcast to observers. However I found that it doesn't quite work the way I'd expect.
This is an example which demonstrates the difference between having two ActionBlocks having all values broadcasted to them and having two IObservers not getting all values:
var broadCastBlock = new BroadcastBlock<int>(i => i);

Func<string, Action<int>> actionGenerator =
(s) => (int i) => Console.WriteLine(s + " " + i);

Action<int> actionFoo = actionGenerator("FOO");
Action<int> actionBar = actionGenerator("BAR");

var actionBlockFoo = new ActionBlock<int>(actionFoo);
var actionBlockBar = new ActionBlock<int>(actionBar);
broadCastBlock.LinkTo(actionBlockFoo);
broadCastBlock.LinkTo(actionBlockBar);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    broadCastBlock.Post(i);
}

Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("-Observable-");
broadCastBlock = new BroadcastBlock<int>(i => i);
var observable = broadCastBlock.AsObservable();
observable.Subscribe(actionFoo);
observable.Subscribe(actionBar);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    broadCastBlock.Post(i);
}
Thread.Sleep(1000);

Output:
BAR 0
FOO 0
FOO 1
BAR 1
BAR 2
BAR 3
BAR 4
FOO 2
FOO 3
FOO 4
-Observable-
FOO 0
BAR 0
FOO 4
BAR 4

Interestingly only the first and the last value get printed. I tested with my own dummy IObserver implementation which yields the same results as the convenience extension method from the code above. This doesn't happen when I use BufferBlock but then again, I am limited to having only one target.
Why is this happening and how can I ensure to get all the values broadcasted to my observers as they are to the ActionBlocks?

Why do you use BroadcastBlock? Why do you not use something else like Subject?

@Progman just trying things out, but this is really puzzling. BufferBlock works as expected.

@IvanPetrov and why user a BufferBlock ? All blocks that produce output have an output buffer.  What is the actual problem you want to solve? This pseudocode doesn't explain this. It's a bad idea to mix up different libraries like Dataflow and Rx when you're trying to learn one of them. Dataflow isn't Rx. Its primary job is to create a pipeline to process a stream of messages. Rx is not built for that, although it's used for that in languages without CSP constructs like Java. Rx is built to analyze a stream of events. thread/task

As for why you can't use an observable instead of a link, because Dataflow knows about links but nothing about the subscribers to the observable. As the BroadcastBlock docs explain BroadcastBlock<T> ensures that the current element is broadcast to any linked targets before allowing the element to be overwritten.. Those targets are specified with LinkTo

@PanagiotisKanavos Subscribe does LinkTo under the hood. It actually hooks up an ActionBlock...so in theory it should work.

The link isn't to the observers, it's to the internal ObjectSource worker block that pushes individual items to the actual observers. Sure, that internal block would cache everything, but the questions code makes another jump from Rx back to Dataflow with .Subscribe(actionFoo)

And in all this, the code never calls broadCastBlock.Complete() and never awaits for the action blocks to complete. It's quite possible the application terminates before the blocks complete. At the very least remove Thread.Sleep, call broadCastBlock.Complete() and at the end. Instead of jumping from Dataflow to Rx and back to Dataflow use observable.Subscribe(number => Console.WriteLine($"FOO: {number}") at least.

BTW the Target ActionBlock is created with BoundedCapacity=1 which means it won't buffer incoming messages. It will cause callers to wait. The question's code sends messages in a tight loop though, faster than Console.WriteLine and even faster than the observer code. That means messages will be overwritten before the observer had a chance to send them to the target blocks.
